# Sort NSArray of NSStrings based on a super set of ordered Strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` which contains some `NSString` objects. For example:

```
NSArray *objects = @[@"Stin",@"Foo",@"Ray",@"Space"];
```

Now I need to sort this array based on following order of Strings.

```
NSArray *sortOrder = @[@"John",@"Foo",@"Space",@"Star",@"Ray",@"Stin"];
```

So the answer should be

```
NSArray *sorted = @[@"Foo",@"Space",@"Ray",@"Stin"];
```

How can I achieve this?

**ANSWER:**
Based on Accepted answer of dasblinkenlight, I did following and it worked to charm.

```
NSMutableArray *objects = @[@"Star",@"Stin",@"Foo",@"Ray",@"Space",@"John"];
NSArray *sortOrder = @[@"John",@"Foo",@"Space",@"Star",@"Ray",@"Stin"];

[objects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    int index1 = [sortOrder indexOfObject:obj1];
    int index2 = [sortOrder indexOfObject:obj2];

    if (index1 > index2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    if (index1 < index2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: What do you want to order it by?

Comment: I store above strings in coredata and when i retrieve them then their order is compromised. So After retreving them from db I wanted to sort them.

Comment: Yeah, but how do you want to sort them? By alphabetical order? By length of string?

Comment: NO, that's the problem. not conventional sorting. As from the strings you see that "John" should always be the first one. So no matter at what index "John" is after retrieval from db it must be re-placed at index 0. If "John" isn't there the @"Foo" gets the highest priority.

Comment: Oh I see, Im not so sure what the answer is... but I favorited it so I can find out later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `NSComparator` that holds a reference to the superset array, and decides the relative order of strings by comparing the results of calling `[superset indexOfObject:str]` on both strings. Call `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` passing an instance of `NSComparator` to get the desired ordering.

Comment: Performance improvement: Store the superset in an lookup dictionary with the string-values as key and the index as number. Than you dont need to do the expensiv `indexOfObject` so often.

Answer (score 3):

dasblinkenlight's solution would work, but like most programming problems there are multiple ways to go about it. Here is one such alternative:

```
NSMutableArray *sorted = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

[sortOrder enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *sortedString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([objects containsObject:sortedString]) {
        [sorted addObject:sortedString];
    }
}];
```

The variable names correspond to the variable names used in the original question.

This works because the enumeration happens in order. Therefore, what takes place is, essentially, a cull of the objects that exist in both arrays in the order as specified by `sortOrder`.

Comment: Also a Good solution, But I guess dasblinkenlight will be cheap in terms of processing...

Comment: I haven't tested them, but from my first glance I would expect mine to actually be faster, as I have one enumeration whereas he has to sort. Until you reach a significant array size, though, the difference in speed will be negligible.